# My card content won't center correctly in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, card

I want to centre all of the content of my cards but it's all going to the right side

my card code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>



  <div class="container mt-5 p-5">

    <div class="row g-4">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card align-items-center bg-light">
          <img src="img/oranvour.png" alt="dfg juice" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Juice</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Price: $199.00</p>

            <div class="form-outline">
              <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber">amount</label>
              <input type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting all of the content to be in the centre of the card not to align-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `text-center` class on `card` like that:

```
<div class="card text-center bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div class="container mt-5 p-5">

    <div class="row g-4">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card text-center bg-light" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669111957903-36e4da270ef1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="" class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Juice</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Price: $199.00</p>

            <div class="form-outline">
              <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber">amount</label>
              <input type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you that worked, How do i add a bit of spacing between the items in the card now?

Comment: @JohnJohnson You 're Welcome ! Glad I Could Help You :-) I think You may use padding property for example p-2... Bootstrap have great docs !

Answer (score 0):

just add "mx-auto" in the class above the card like this :

```
<div class="container mt-5 p-5">
  <div class="row g-4">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mx-auto">
      <div class="card align-items-center bg-light">
        <img src="img/oranvour.png" alt="dfg juice" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Juice</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Price: $199.00</p>

            <div class="form-outline">
              <label class="form-label" for="typeNumber">amount</label>
              <input type="number" id="typeNumber" class="form-control" />
          </div>                      
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div/>
```